# Numeric transaction modes are deprecated in IDBDatabase.transaction. Use "readonly" or "readwrite"

Tags: indexeddb

I have been getting this warning on my application that is using IndexedDB.

"Numeric transaction modes are deprecated in IDBDatabase.transaction. Use "readonly" or "readwrite""

which I didn't see that when I first wrote the app (about few months ago) but appear to get this warning every time it tries to access IDBDatabase.transaction.

on chrome console, it can properly recognize the following transaction key.

```
IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE
1
IDBTransaction.READ_ONLY
0
```

my example code that is doing IDB transaction:

```
IndexedDB.set = function(key, obj, onsuccess, oncomplete) {
    var db = IndexedDB.db;
    var trans = db.transaction([key], IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE);
    var objectStore = trans.objectStore(key);
    var request = objectStore.put(obj);

    request.onsuccess = function(e) {
      if (onsuccess !== undefined)
        onsuccess(request.result);
    };

    request.onerror = function(e) {
      console.log("Database error: " + e.target.errorCode);
    };
    trans.oncomplete = function(e) {
      if (oncomplete !== undefined)
        oncomplete(request.result);
    };
  };
```

should I have to worry about this? if so, how can I avoid this warning?

my chrome v: Version 21.0.1180.75

thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The IndexedDB standard is still a work in progress (although version 1 is very close to finished), and one of the recent changes was [switching from the numeric constants like "IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE" to just plain strings like "readwrite"](http://old.nabble.com/-IndexedDB--Numeric-constants-vs-enumerated-strings-to33370626.html#a33370626). It's a good idea because it makes code more concise and more readable.

The old constants will likely continue to work for some time, albeit with a warning message like you observed, but using the strings is the "correct" way to do it now and that's probably what you should use, like:

```
    var trans = db.transaction([key], "readwrite");
```

Comment: thanks Jeremy for the quick response. after switching it over to string, the warning went away and all the functionality still works. do you know if this change is applied to all the chrome version? (worked with Version 21.0.1180.75)

Comment: Chrome 20 was the first version that supported the new strings.

Comment: thanks Jeremy, does that mean if I switch to string, Chrome v < 20 would not work?

Comment: Correct. You can either keep using the old constants and ignore the error messages, switch to strings and ignore old browsers, or do something like the other answer and support both. In most cases I'd recommend just using the strings, as old versions of FF and Chrome are rarely used due to automatic updates, but YMMV.

Answer (score 4):

For backwards compatibility I would advice to provide a fallback. For chrome, I would ignore the warning you get and stay using the the interface.

Maybe try the following work around to make it backwords and forwards compatible:

```
var transactionType = { READ_ONLY: "readonly", READ_WRITE: "readwrite" }
if (IDBTransaction.READ_ONLY && IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE){
   transactionType.READ_ONLY = IDBTransaction.READ_ONLY
   transactionType.READ_WRITE = IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE
}

var trans = db.transaction([key], transactionType.READ_WRITE);
```

With this solution, you make sure old browser will still work and new one's too.

Comment: since IDBTransaction.READ_ONLY is 0. Won't JavaScript translate it as false?

Comment: No javascript isn't a strong typed language, but it recognize types. if you want to use true or false in JS you need to use the keywords true and false