# Unable to add data to indexeddb objectstore

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, indexeddb

I am using the [jquery-indexed-db plugin](https://github.com/axemclion/jquery-indexeddb/blob/gh-pages/docs/README.md) to make a sample project just to go about learning [indexeddb](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/).

**JS CODE**

```
$(function() {
    /*Loggers*/
    write = function(info) {
        console.info(info);
    }

    writeError = function(e) {
        console.info(e);
    }

    /*Settings*/
    dbName = "testDB";
    osName = "list";

    /*DB Init*/
    db = $.indexedDB(dbName).then(write, writeError)

    /*ObjectStore Init*/
    objectStore = db.objectStore(osName, false);

    /*Adding a new record*/
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        objectStore.add( 
            {
                "Name": $("#name").val(),
                "Age": $("#age").val()
            },
            $("#id").val()
        ).then(write, writeError);

        $("#id").val("");
        $("#name").val("");
        $("#age").val("");

    });

});
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="text" id="id" placeholder="Id" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="text" id="age" placeholder="Age" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I am getting an exception when i click the submit button. The error is as follows

```
IDBDatabaseException
code: 11
message: "InvalidStateError: DOM IDBDatabase Exception 11"
name: "InvalidStateError"
stack: "Error: An operation was called on an object on which it is not allowed or at a time when    it is not allowed.↵    at null.<anonymous>    (file:///*****/js/jquery.indexeddb.js:468:33)↵    at n (file:///******/js/jquery.js:1:14837)↵    at Object.o.add [as done] (file:///******/js/jquery.js:1:15052)↵    at Object.h.then (file:///******/js/jquery.js:1:16026)↵    at Object.<anonymous> (file:///******/js/jquery.indexeddb.js:465:17)↵    at Function.f.extend.Deferred (file:///******/js/jquery.js:1:16742)↵    at Object.$.extend.transaction (file:///******/js/jquery.indexeddb.js:464:15)↵    at Object.<anonymous> (file:///******/js/jquery.indexeddb.js:516:11)↵    at Function.f.extend.Deferred (file:///******/js/jquery.js:1:16742)↵    at op (file:///******/js/jquery.indexeddb.js:501:16)" type: "exception"
```

Am I doing something wrong?

I am using Google Chrome (Version 22.0.1229.94)

Comment: Try my lib https://bitbucket.org/ytkyaw/ydn-db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a transaction before you can open an object store.

```
$.indexedDB(dbName).transaction([osName], 1).then(function(transaction){
    objectStore = transaction.objectStore(osName);
});
```

Btw is that the complete script you gave? I'm missing the part where you create an object store.

Comment: Although I added your code, i dont think an indexed db has been created. There is no indexedDB in Resources of my dev tools. Also, I used ["readwrite" instead of 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974115/numeric-transaction-modes-are-deprecated-in-idbdatabase-transaction-use-readon) in the transaction.

Comment: If you don't see anything there, it is possible that it isn't created. Did you get any errors now? I don't know what you are willing to do, but I also have build a wrapper. (http://linq2indexeddb.codeplex.com)

Comment: The error was that my object store was not created. Thanks, your answer lead me in the right direction